# Spring, hibernate, досту к бд из потока рожденного внешней библиотекой

Tags: многопоточность, hibernate, spring-mvc

В потоке, который порождается внешней библиотекой, необходимо получить данные из БД. 
Но при попытке обратиться к sessionFactory вылетает NullPointerException.
Как правильно разрешить такую ситуацию?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

В *persistence.xml* добавьте свойство "`hibernate.session_factory_name`" (если его там ещё нет).

```
<persistence-unit name="myJta">
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.session_factory_name" value="java:/hibernate/MyFactory"/>
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

В вашем коде делайте так:

```
InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext();
sessionFactory = (SessionFactory) ctx.lookup(java:/hibernate/MyFactory);
Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
```